# visual studio path, unknown user

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have an issue in Visual studio 2013.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\project.pdf")
    If IO.File.Exists(Name) Then
        MsgBox("Login launched")
    End If
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

I'd like to change the "USER" part so that no matter which computer this is on, it will find the correct file/path. This is something I could do in a batch file, like this: `"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\project.pdf"`

This part "%username%"

Thank you in advance,

P.S.

If at all possible, I'd like to have it so, no matter where the user has the certain .pdf it would always find the right path to it. So basically the user chooses where to install the file and then it reads from that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the first question is:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\project.pdf";
```

or (depends on what you want to do)

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + @"\project.pdf";
```